# Sort a multidimentional array in javascript based on two dimensions?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has a numeric dimension and and a string dimention.

```
arr = [12, "suffix", 12, "prefix", 2, "suffix", 0, "prefix"]
```

I want to sort it by number (smallest to largest) and then from A-Z (so that prefix comes before suffix).

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not "multidimensional", and I don't know what the expected result should be.

Comment: "I have an array that has a numeric dimension and and a string dimention" — No, you don't. You have a flat array consisting of alternating strings and numbers. You should probably have an array of objects, each with two properties, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply sort it twice:

```
[12, "suffix", 12, "prefix", 2, "suffix", 0, "prefix"]
 .sort()
 .sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
// == [0, 2, 12, 12, "prefix", "prefix", "suffix", "suffix"]
```

this uses the built-in text sort and a simple numerical value sort that works on numbers and dates.

for more complicated elements or huge sets when perf matters, it might be faster/better to write a custom multi-criteria `.sort()` callback yourself, tailored to the data and need.